# Do faulty 100mb half-duplex connections flood a subnet with collision traffic?

Tags: networking, routing, network-protocols

I'm on a subnet where a lot of machines are falsely getting set to 100 megabit half-duplex connections. Could this potentially slow down other machines on the network that have proper full-duplex connections? Or am I wrong that the half-duplex connections wouldn't clog the switch with unnecessary traffic? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, computers running half duplex will not slow down computers running full duplex. Today almost everyone uses switches. With a switch each Ethernet cable running from switch to computer is its own collision domain. So what is happening on one cable has no affect on the others.